# VueJS 3 registering import globally

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs3, inertiajs

I got a simple question probably but I am not really finding out how to do it.

I want to use [Sweetalert2](https://sweetalert2.github.io/) and use it globally in every VueJS component I have.
So in my app.js I have this:

```
import { createApp, h } from 'vue'
import { createInertiaApp } from '@inertiajs/inertia-vue3'
import { Head, Link } from '@inertiajs/inertia-vue3'
import { InertiaProgress } from '@inertiajs/progress'
import { Swal } from 'sweetalert2'


createInertiaApp({
  resolve: name => require(`./Pages/${name}`),
  setup({ el, App, props, plugin }) {
    createApp({ render: () => h(App, props) })
      .use(plugin)
      .use(Swal)
      .component('Link', Link)
      .component('Head', Head)
      .mount(el)
  },
})
```

For some reason this still gives this error:
[(Picture)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PCfWC.png)

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried using default import

```
import Swal from 'sweetalert2'
```

Answer (score 0):

```
.component('Swal',require('sweetalert2').default);
```

in order to make any component available for all vue components have to mention as default
did you try this way?

Comment: Still stays that it isn't defined :/

Comment: Does it work when you import in local component?

Answer (score 0):

Try to install this npm package :
https://www.npmjs.com/package/vue-sweetalert2
It's made for vue 2 and 3